# How to actually find expect in debian bullseye?

Tags: debian, apt

I have debian 11 (bullseye) on my system and want to install expect - but it doesn't seem to be known to apt, although it should be there according to [this](https://packages.debian.org/en/bullseye/expect):

```
# apt-get install expect
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package expect
```

It may be that I have somehow corrupted my apt configuration (although I haven't knowingly touched anything); the reason I suspect this is that I decided to try to uninstall apt-file and reinstall it because it behaved strangely - now apt-get says it can't find it.

What could be the reason?

Comment: did you run `apt-get update` first? the package `expect` is there.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, I did run apt-get update. What confuses me is that it also can't find a package I had installed previously and now wanted to reinstall.

Comment: Take a look at the [questions and answers regarding `apt broken` over at the Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=apt+broken).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've looked through the suggestions, but found nothing that addresses my issue. I'll try my question over there, if this isn't the right forum.

Comment: I already voted to migrate your question over. Cross posting is not allowed on most SE sites. But I've seen answers that should address exactly your issue. You most probably need to download and reinstall the .deb files for apt manually.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to reinstall the server and restore backups though.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I actually found the solution by accident just now: someone/something (and it certainly wasn't me) had commented out every line in source.list. Hard to guess why, but there you are!

Comment: Then please post this as an answer and don't forget to accept it when you can.